# Scheduling Sybase IQ SQL code to run every day

Tags: sql, scheduled-tasks, sap-iq

I have some SQL code that I need to run each day which I use to pull the latest data so that my Tableau dashboard has the most up to date data for management to view.

As you can see I get the most up to date data for the prior 6 weeks

My example code is as follows

```
SELECT *
FROM fictitious_table
WHERE dcla.DAY BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -6, TODAY()) AND DATEADD(dd, -1, TODAY())  -- USES 6 WEEK ROLLING WINDOW
```

I have read about creating events in IQ and so I came up with the following code based on the examples provided.

```
CREATE EVENT DAILY_RX
SCHEDULE
START TIME '1:00 pm' EVERY 24 HOURS
HANDLER
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myName.DAILY_RX;
INSERT INTO myName.DAILY_RX
SELECT *
    FROM fictitious_table
    WHERE dcla.DAY BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -6, TODAY()) AND DATEADD(dd, -1, TODAY())  -- USES 6 WEEK ROLLING WINDOW
END;
```

When I try to run the code it errors out due to syntax error "[Code: 102, SQL State: 42W04]  SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'END' on line 92"

The example I copied from didn't have a drop table statement so this is where I think I am falling down.

What is the best/most efficient way I can get the latest 6 weeks data and store it in my table?

Comment: can't speak to the error message other than to ask ... if you `drop` the table don't you then have to `create` the table before you can `insert into` the table?  alternatively ... `drop` + `select into` ... or ... `truncate table` + `insert into` ... ?

Comment: a quick glance at a few examples in the manuals seem to show that in a multi-statement `BEGIN/END` block all statements should end with a semi-colon (`;`) soooo, I'm wondering if a `;` at the end of the `insert ... select` might be needed? this would tend to support the error message stating a syntax issue near `END` (ie, the parser is expecting to see a `;` on the end of the `insert ... select` statement and before the `END`) ... ?

Comment: **NOTE:** I'm assuming the example you copied was of a single-statement `BEGIN/END` block ... and the examples of those I've found in the manuals seem to show the `;` is not needed (for a single-statement `BEGIN/END` block).

Comment: @markp-fuso thanks for the reply. I removed the drop table and the last semi colon and the script executed correctly but turns our I do not have permission to create events on the database : (